# frequency generator and power supplies

Tags: power-supply, frequency

I am going to do mini-project (school level), for which I need a **power supply** (in the range of +5v dc supply) from ac main (230v, 50Hz) and **frequency generator** (for a range up to some kHz, sine wave).

Since it is a mini-project, money is the main criteria. Is it best choice to have circuits for supply and generator, or any devices for them that reduces the cost of project.

Give the circuits of power supplies and function generators.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shopping question and will likely get closed. For a 5V power supply, you can use a regular AC to 5V charger for cell phones, just cut one side of a USB cable and take the VCC and GND lines. Should work well enough.

For a signal generator, you didn't specify if you just needed sine wave or more, but an AD9850 DDS Signal Generator board which is very cheap on eBay will be good enough for your applications. Goes for around $5.